# using a push fit valve as a cap

Tags: pushfit

If you use a 1/2" CPVC push fit ball valve as a cap on a 1/2" copper pipe, is it possible that the water pressure could eventually send the valve flying off the end of the pipe? That'd result in a lot more serious water problem than just a mere leak. I'm thinking more in terms of a few months or years rather than 15-20 years into the future.

I looked but haven't found any reports of anything like that actually happening.

Comment: You can buy push-fit end-caps and presumably they don't regularly fly off the ends of pipes - so I don't see any reason your push-fit valve would be any different.

Comment: right. would you expect the valve to be flying off a pipe if it was closed and installed inline?

Comment: @aaron I wouldn't have very high expectations of any plumbing system that used pvc valves on copper pipes.